# How should a martial arts instructor assess remote students?

Tags: self-training, covid-19

How should a martial arts instructor go about assessing their students from a remote setting? Are there any core metrics they could use to review a students self-training from within a app?

My original question was deemed a "polling" question. As I am not an instructor, I wanted the valuable point of views from martial arts instructors. Basically I want to build an app, I have the core app idea, my core customer are instructors, and I want to include additional features that an instructor would deem necessary.

What I ultimately want to know, what would an instructor deem vital in a self-training app for their students? Including but not limited to analytics, but what kind of analytics would be of interest to an instructor?

But to ask this type of question, I have been told to join other websites.

I left my original question in place as guidance to the problem I was trying to solve but that was removed.

@Macaco Branco has stated its difficult to correct an individual student in an online group session. Therefore I can pull this out as a requirement. "add a feature to select and ping a student privately during a session" This could work that their screen shakes, plays a noise, flashing color boarders or all three. Something like that

Comment: Depends, assessing them in what? basics? Padwork? Drills? Forms? Sparring? Weapons?

Comment: hi @KristinaLex this question has been heavily edited by someone who deleted the entire context included removing the tag self-training. The above is to be frame in an app, not with 1:1 video such as zoom, but as a tool for self training.

Comment: @mushcraft: If so, you want that to be in the question.

Comment: What does it mean to have self-training with an instructor? That is a contradiction of the definition of the tag.

Comment: I edited the question to be your second, non-poll question because that is in scope of the main site, but now we are back to, "please tell me how to create a killer app". If you have the core idea, why do you need help with marginal features like flashing borders?

Comment: You are also always free to use the [chat room for this site:](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79444/open-roda).

Comment: @mattm `What does it mean to have self-training with an instructor? That is a contradiction of the definition of the tag.` instructor sets drills for you to do in your self-training. Instructor can then review.  `If you have the core idea, why do you need help with marginal features like flashing borders?` because without those features I have the potential of building a app my ideal customer has no use for it.

Comment: I do recommend the chat room. Drop me a comment when you join. I don't always check every day.

Answer (score 3):

To some degree, there is no real difference between observing a student via a Zoom session and observing them in-person from a judging table, as is generally done for testing. You only have a single point of view, but you can more or less watch them real-time. If you're having difficulty observing fluidity of movement due to transmission issues, you could go with a video submission.

As regards observation during class, I'll admit that that is an issue, and something I've been thinking about in the process of my remote Capoeira classes. Typically, you have X different windows for the different students, which makes it harder to look at the overall picture and note when someone isn't getting it right, made slightly harder by that the issues in synchronization of video feeds means everyone's moving at a slightly different rhythm, eliminating the "one of these things is not like the others" metric. The only concrete observation I've gotten out of it is you generally need to set up a situation where they'll do X repetitions of the movement, where X is some multiple of the number of students, and you spread your attention from one student to the next to see if they're getting it right. That also means that teaching a class starts to lose the exercise benefit of doing the class yourself, since if you're doing the movement, you often can't divide your attention to observe everyone else. Add to that that you often don't have the benefit of assistant instructors since you're managing a limited number of seats in the video sessions, and it does get more difficult.

The other issue I've seen is that it's much harder to privately call people out. In general, everyone hears everything, and your students are unlikely to notice a chat message in the midst of movements. This may be something that you'll just discuss with your students, that corrections in class are generally not criticisms, and make sure that you also call out affirmations for people getting it right so that they know that they're not being ignored. Really, it's the same sort of thing as in public sessions where you're yelling out from the front of class rather than walking amidst the drilling students.